# Use PHP variable in a SELECT LIKE query

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to execute a mysqli query using the following code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `description` LIKE ('AB CD %')";
$result= mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());
```

and this query gives me 6 results. It will only looks for items like "AB CD EF..." and not items like "AB CDEF...", which is exactly what I want.
But if I give to the LIKE value a variable like this:

```
$var = "AB CD ";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `description` LIKE ('$var%')";
$result= mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());
```

it gives me zero results.

I have tried also several LIKE formats such `...('".$var."%')";` or `CONCAT($var, '%')`, but nothing.

How can get the same results as the first query usin a variable like in the sencond query?

The variable is get by a query which will select all `description` items and then, inside a while loop, it will look for the first Capital letters of each item:

```
$name = $row['description'];
$expr = '/[A-Z]*/';
preg_match_all($expr, $name, $res);
$var = implode(' ', $res[0]);
```

Each row has values like "AB CD EF something else in not capital letters"

Thank you.

Comment: how about `$var = 'AB CD %';` ?

Comment: Yes, tried, also.

Comment: Maybe is important to refer how I get the variable. I will edit the post

Comment: Yes that is very much important. I guess you need to escape the string also.

Comment: How about using prepared statements...

Comment: @dnFer 's comment should be extended to be "prepared statements and positional parameters and binding"

Comment: I have to confess my simple knowledge on coding. Isn't this "prepared statements and positional parameters and binding" an object oriented coding? Probably is simple but I'm not comfortable about this method. I will investigate

Comment: `var_dump($sql);` gives back what?

Comment: if I use the first query (without the variable):object(mysqli_result)#4 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(21) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(6) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: If I use the query with variable: object(mysqli_result)#4 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(21) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: `$sql` in the code your provided should be a string, not an object..

Comment: sorry I made the var dump for the $result. for the $sql the result is: string(86) "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `description` LIKE 'AB CD %'"

Comment: In this case I used the code of the first answer below.

Comment: Well thats a problem. You must have hidden characters. There's only 52 characters in that string but your dump has 86.

Comment: So the problem is in the implode of array(1) { [0]=> array(27) { [0]=> string(2) "AB" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(2) "CD" [3]=> string(0) "" [4]=> string(0) "" [5]=> string(0) "" [6]=> string(0) "" [7]=> string(0) "" [8]=> string(0) "" [9]=> string(0) "" [10]=> string(0) "" [11]=> string(0) "" [12]=> string(0) "" [13]=> string(0) "" [14]=> string(0) "" [15]=> string(0) "" [16]=> string(0) "" [17]=> string(0) "" [18]=> string(0) "" [19]=> string(0) "" [20]=> string(0) "" [21]=> string(0) "" [22]=> string(0) "" [23]=> string(0) "" [24]=> string(0) "" [25]=> string(0) "" [26]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: Which is the length of the item but without the words in capital letters

Comment: Those are all empty strings though. They wouldn't add to the length. Split the string, iterate over it and see what every character is. https://3v4l.org/EYN2E

Answer (score 1):

How about this after wrapping the variable with curly braces `{}`? Also I just removed the extra parenthesis `()` after **LIKE** :)

```
$var = "AB CD ";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `description` LIKE '{$var}%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, user3783243 found the problem.
When I implode the array to get the $var in a string, for some reason I cannot explain, the array elements (a lot of them) that had no value were included. The solution was to explode the $var, pass it through the array_filter function, to delete the empty elements and implode it again.
Thank you all.

Answer (score -1):

Use :

```
$var = "AB CD ";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `description` LIKE '".$var."%'";
```

But this is a bad practice as well as highly vulnerable, use prepared statement instead : http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: That is the same as what the OP has. PDO can be just as secure/insecure as mysqli.